# Spring.xml error config

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I have this error when run spring project by -cp

java -cp "parser.jar" hu.daniel.hari.learn.spring.orm.main.SpringOrmMain

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/p]
```

Offending resource: class path resource [spring.xml]

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.decorateIfRequired(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1464)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.decorateBeanDefinitionIfRequired(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.decorateBeanDefinitionIfRequired(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
```

My beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        ">

```
<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered 
    as Spring beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="hu.daniel.hari.learn.spring" />
<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes e.g: @Autowired -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" /> <property 
    name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem://productDb" /> <property name="username" 
    value="sa" /> <property name="password" value="" /> </bean> -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/newparser" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="postgres" />
    <!--<property name="socketTimeout" value="10"/> -->

    <property name="connectionProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="socketTimeout">10</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:packagesToScan="hu.daniel.hari.learn.spring.orm.model"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transactions -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Comment: aren't you missing opening and closing the <beans /> tag at the topmost level?

Answer (score 0):

Add namespace for the shorthand property (`p:`)

```
<beans 
...
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
```